# Can I use a template from SP O365 to create a library in the on-site version of SP?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-365, template

I have a calendar in O365 that I need to re-create in the on-site version of SP.  Can I create a template of the calendar in O365 and use that to create the calendar in the on-site version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create a template of a calendar in Office 365 SharePoint Online, then use it in SharePoint On-premise. Right?

If you are using SharePoint 2016/2019 on-premise, you can save the calendar in a SharePoint online site then use it in On-premise site.

Steps:
1. In SharePoint Online site, go to the calendar->**List Settings**->**Save list as template**
2. Go to **Site settings**->**List Templates**, find the new template and click to download
3. Copy and paste the template file(.stp) into your On-premise environment
4. Go to your On-premise site and go to **Site Settings**->b, upload the template file into it
5. Now, you can create a new list using the template